# How to disable button based on state of other button

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to create 2 buttons in react app using material ui buttons with both buttons are enabled at the start of page load. When onClick on one of the button, the other button should be disabled vice versa.

[Initial state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0nkg.png)

[When onClick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43EZ4.png)

```html
const [btn1, setBtn1] = useState(false);
const [btn2, setBtn2] = useState(false);

const onBtn1 = () => {
        setBtn1(!btn1);
    };

    const onBtn2 = () => {
        setBtn2(!btn2);
    };
}
```

How do i go about doing it? is there anyway to just use a single useState hook to handle 2 state buttons?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with only one state `variable` and one `function`

### Code

```
const [disabledButton, setDisabledButton] = useState('');      

const onButtonClick = (param) => {
  setDisabledButton(param);
}    

<Button onClick={() => onButtonClick('btn2')} disabled={disabledButton === 'btn1'}>
   Button 1
</Button>
<Button onClick={() => onButtonClick('btn1')} disabled={disabledButton === 'btn2'}>
   Button 2
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just enable the other button when a button is clicked:

```
const onBtn1 = () => {
   setBtn1(prevState => !prevState);
   setBtn2(false);
};

const onBtn2 = () => {
   setBtn2(prevState => !prevState);
   setBtn1(false);
};
```

in the JSX:

```
<button onClick={onBtn1} disabled={btn1}>btn1</button>
<button onClick={onBtn2} disabled={btn2}>btn2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the state of other button on press.

```
const [btn1, setBtn1] = useState(true);  //Initially both buttons are enabled
const [btn2, setBtn2] = useState(true);

const onBtn1 = () => {
        setBtn1(!btn1);
        setBtn2(false);
    };

    const onBtn2 = () => {
        setBtn2(!btn2);
        setBtn1(false);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a single state, please refer the suggestion below:

state and event handlers-

```
const [activeButton, setActiveButton] = useState("None");


const onBtn1 = () => {
        setActiveButton("Button1");
    };


const onBtn2 = () => {
        setActiveButton("Button2");
    };
```

HTML Element part -

```
<Button disabled={!['None', 'Button1'].includes(activeButton)}>Button1</Button>
<Button disabled={!['None', 'Button2'].includes(activeButton)}>Button2</Button>
```